# keep getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main?

Tags: java, runtime-error

Here's my code. I don't understand why I keep getting this?

It's supposed to recursively change bases from base ten to any given base.

Any help would be awesome.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Recursion{

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                try {   System.out.println(" Please input the base you would like to convert into " );
                        Scanner BaseIn = new Scanner (System.in);
                        int base1 = BaseIn.nextInt();

                        System.out.println( "Now input the number you would like to convert" );
                        Scanner NumIn = new Scanner (System.in);
                        int number = NumIn.nextInt();

                        BaseConversion (number, base1);
                    }

                catch (Exception e)
                {
                System.out.print("somethigng stupid");
                }
        }

        public String BaseConversion(int num, int base)
        {
                if (num < base)
                {
                return new String ("" + num);
                }
                else
                {
                return BaseConversion (num/base, base) + new String("" + (num % base));
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the output what you are trying to get?Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method BaseConversion(int, int).

Comment: How did that code of yours even compiled? And you should never run a code that contains a Compiler Error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a non-static reference from a static context.
Your above code will not even compile, as you are trying to invoke non-static method (BaseConversion) from your static main method..

Try running your code after making your BaseConversion Method `static`..

Suggestion: - Do follow coding convention, to make your code more meaningful.. Your method and variable names always follow Camel Case (Start with lowercase, and subsequent word with Capital letters)

Answer (score 0):

You must give the name of the *class* to run, not the *method*.

In this case

```
java Recursion
```

Answer (score 0):

`BaseConversion` is instance method and you need instance of class to access it.

so you should invoke it like this

```
`new Recursion().baseConversion(number, base1)` //I have changed name according to java conventions.
```

Else declare it as `static`

Your class will look like below. You can now proceed with your logic

```
public class Recursion {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out
                .println(" Please input the base you would like to convert into ");
        Scanner BaseIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int base1 = BaseIn.nextInt();

        System.out
                .println("Now input the number you would like to convert");
        Scanner NumIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = NumIn.nextInt();

        System.out.println(new Recursion().baseConversion(number, base1));
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("somethigng stupid");
    }
}

public String baseConversion(int num, int base) {
    if (num < base) {
        return new String("" + num);
    } else {
        return baseConversion(num / base, base)
                + new String("" + (num % base));
    }
}

}
```